# Android service stopping

Tags: android, service

If I stop service from activity:

```
Intent locationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            LocationService.class);
    stopService(locationIntent);
```

and  override service's onDestroy method so that it does not call `super.onDestroy()`

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //super.onDestroy();
}
```

will it still be alive?

Comment: Try it out and see for yourself

Comment: But I think it will give a compilation error if you omit super.onDestroy()

Comment: This seems to me to be a homework question anyway...

Comment: No, it is not. I am working on some code that guy before me worked on. I saw somewhere in code that he had ommited super.onDestroy, and now I am trying to find out why did he do so.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not be alive.  The `onDestroy()` method allows you to cleanup any resources your `Service` may have allocated for its operation, but it does not affect the lifecycle of the component itself.